# ios: if wifi range is weak then also access the internet within timeout interval using reachability

Tags: ios, timeout, reachability

I am new in ios. i have develop a practice app, where i use rechability for network connection. but i have problem in that, when network is weak it shows the 'No network' message.

but i want in weak signal, it should access the internet within a 30sec timeout  interval.

How Can i access the internet in weak signal within timeout interval.

I have tried the following:

```
-(BOOL)getInternetConnectionStatus
{
  Reachability *objReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];                              
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [objReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
BOOL boolInternet;
if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN))
{
    boolInternet = NO;

}
else
{
    boolInternet = YES;
}
return boolInternet;
```

}

-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    // call web service

```
if (![self getInternetConnectionStatus])
{
    UIAlertView *alertMessage=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"No Internet Connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alertMessage show];
    return;
}
else
{

    NSData *dataReply;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    // create the request
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://Your link" ];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                          timeoutInterval:0.3];
    // Make the connection
    dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (response != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"SNNetworkController.isHostAvailable %@", response);
        UIAlertView *alertMessage=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Wel-Come" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertMessage show];

    }
    else
    {
        // inform the user that the download could not be made
        NSLog(@"SNNetworkController.isHostAvailable %@ %@", response, error);
        UIAlertView *alertMessage=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"No Internet Connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertMessage show];

     }
}
```

}

But it shows the message 'No Internet Connection' when signal is weak.
how can i shows the 'Wel-come' message within timeout when signal is weak.
   Please give me the answer....

Thanks in advanced....!!!

Comment: Rather checking connection with **Google**, try with your site. So change your code in `getInternetConnectionStatus` method like: `Reachability *objReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://Your link"];`. This is just a best practice to do, it is not related to solve the issue.